# Is it possible to hide a class parent when exported to COM with ComVisible?

Tags: c#, delphi, com

In a C# class library (.Net 3.5), I have a very simple class (some string and long properties, no methods) which inherit from [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapheader%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). My class is tagged as ComVisible(true) because I need to use it in Delphi.

For some unknown reason, this class can't be created in Delphi, when the class interface is automatically exported (aka attribute ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)).
I made a simple C++ program to test about that, and I get each time the same error: 0x80131509 (Methods parameters or return type cannot be invoked via IDispatch).
After some digging, the problem is directly related to SoapHeader. When I remove it or use it as property of my class, all run fine.

In C++, when using IDispatch to access my class exported with ClassInterfaceType.None, all work fine.
But I can't relay on IDispatch in Delphi, so I'm searching a way to avoid the type library exporter to export SoapHeader stuff.

Is there a way to do that ? A .Net attribute to inform the type library exporter to avoid exposing a class parent ? To expose only a part of a class even if there is more stuff ?

Comment: What exactly did you intend to expose through the interface?  Native COM interfaces (non-IDispatch) probably expect a non-empty vtable, and you have zero methods on it. So did you try adding methods named `getProperty1' and `getProperty2` instead of relying on properties to magically work without any vtable entries for the get property methods?

Answer (score 4):

Declare an interface so you can explicitly name the members that are visible to COM clients.  Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IThingsIWantToExpose {
    void mumble();
    // etc..
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MyComClass : SomeBaseClass, IThingsIWantToExpose {
    // Actual implementation of the methods
    public void mumble() { }
    // etc, plus everything else that you want to do in the class
    //...
}
```

Using ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual allows both early and late binding (IDispatch).  ClassInterfaceType.None hides the class members so the base class isn't exposed either.  Including the System.Object members btw.

Comment: It's a good idea, but Delphi 7 is not able to "see" an interface. So it run well in C++ but not in Delphi.

Comment: Hmm, this generates a standard COM coclass and type library.  Delphi should not have any problem with it.  I don't know Delphi, be sure to create a type library with Regasm /codebase /tlb and import the .tlb

Comment: It's exactly what we tried some minutes ago, and Delphi 7 don't see it. You know, Delphi 7 is quite old (2002), it's a real pain but ... legacy is legacy :)
I edit the question to remove the ambiguity about interface. The last phrase was not very clear.

Comment: Delphi 7 can consume and expose COM objects perfectly well. Is your COM object 64 bit? Delphi is 32 bit.

Comment: I'm definitively not a Delphi expert, but I don't see how Delphi can consume interface as this concept seem unknown to Delphi.
That's an interesting point ! Effectively, the Assembly is compiled with "Any CPU" target platform, and my computer is a Windows 7 64bits.

Comment: What matters is how you register it, use either the 32-bit or the 64-bit version of Regasm.exe.  Or both.  But that can't be it, consuming a type library doesn't require registration.  It doesn't come into play until you run your program.

Comment: By interface, I mean .Net interface like IThingsIWantToExpose.
Oh yeah, sorry I was not clear: Delphi see and import the .tlb without problem, but  I can't instantiate an IThingsIWantToExpose object.

Comment: *All* COM servers expose their methods through interfaces, that's how COM works.  Don't confuse the implementation details of .NET with the abilities of Delphi.  You need to find a Delphi expert that can show you how to import the type library properly.  Or google "delphi import type library".  The first hit looks good.

Comment: It seem you're right David H. ! I can now instantiate correctly my COM with my C++ 32bits test program. We still have to try in Delphi (not me, one of my colleague) but I think it's gonna be ok. Thank to both of for your help :)

Comment: Ask another question, this doesn't have anything to do anymore with this question.